# php - echo select value without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, snipcart

I have a clothing website using snipcart which currently has no built in size or color selector so i need to do it myself by putting it in the description so we can know what to send. Anyway, i need the selected value of the color and size to be echoed in the button data.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    echo"<h4 class='ct3'>COLOR</h4>
<select id='color' name='color'>
$colorsHTML;
</select>

<h4 class='ct3'>SIZE</h4>
<select name='size' id='size'>
$sizesHTML;
</select>

<br>
<br>
<button
    class='snipcart-add-item list-group-item ct3 add_to_cart' style='background-color: black; color: white;'
    data-item-id='2'
    data-item-name='$name'
    data-item-price='$price'
    data-item-weight='0'
    data-item-url=''
    data-item-image='$image'
    data-item-description='$description'>
        ADD TO CART
</button>";
?>
```

I need the color and size to be echoed in the button's data so it will look like this:

```
    <?php
echo"<h4 class='ct3'>COLOR</h4>
    <select id='color' name='color'>
    $colorsHTML;
    </select>

    <h4 class='ct3'>SIZE</h4>
    <select name='size' id='size'>
    $sizesHTML;
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>
    <button
        class='snipcart-add-item list-group-item ct3 add_to_cart' style='background-color: black; color: white;'
        data-item-id='2'
        data-item-name='$name'
        data-item-price='$price'
        data-item-weight='0'
        data-item-url=''
        data-item-image='$image'
        data-item-description='$description  COLOR=blue SIZE=XL'>
            ADD TO CART
    </button>";
?>
```

I've tried this:
but i think i would need a code for it to change the button data when the value for the select input is changed

```
<button
    class='snipcart-add-item list-group-item ct3 add_to_cart' style='background-color: black; color: white;'
    data-item-id='2'
    data-item-name='$name'
    data-item-price='$price'
    data-item-weight='0'
    data-item-url=''
    data-item-image='$image'
    data-item-description='$description COLOR = <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#color').select(function() {
       var model=$('#color').val();
      alert(model);
     });</script>  SIZE = <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#size').select(function() {
       var model=$('#size').val();
      alert(model);
     });
</script>'>
        ADD TO CART
</button>
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @NishantNair I think the only way is to put the selected value in the button data-item-desription on change

Comment: Have you tried anything or just waiting for us to write you code?

Comment: I've tried to echo a jquery code inside the data-item-description but its just echos the jquery code so i need help

Comment: SHow us what you tried __please__

Comment: @u_mulder okay, updated the post to show what i did, check at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can only be achieved by some client side scripting language like JS or Jquery like:

Html:

```
<select id="size">
  <option value="small">Small</option>
  <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>

<div id="response">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#size').change(function(){
    $('#response').html($(this).val());
    // $('#response').attr('data-item-description', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xw486ca/)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xw486ca/1/)

**Note:** Don't forget to include jquery library

Comment: ok but is there a way to insert it into my data-item-description instead of just echoing in a div?

Answer (score 0):

For setting `data`-properties of an element there's a special [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function in jquery:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( "#size" ).change( function() { 
        // get value of a selected option
        var val = $( this ).val(); 
        // set data-attribute of a button
        $( "button" ).data( "color", val );
    } );

    $( "#color" ).change( function() { 
        // get value of a selected option
        var val = $( this ).val(); 
        // set data-attribute of a button
        $( "button" ).data( "size", val );
    } );
} );
```

Note, that `size` and `color` will be data-attributes. This means that in your button they will look like:

```
<button data-item-description='$description'  data-color='blue' data-size='XL'>
```

Comment: is there a way to put the color and size in the description with the $description variable?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but if you want to add color and size to a `description` this means that sometimes you need to __remove__ previously selected color and size. In this case this is a job for regular expressions. So I advise you to use distinct data attributes.

Comment: the reason i cant use new data types is because snipcart doesnt support these data types so putting it in the description is the only solution

Comment: Did you see the custom fields offered by Snipcart? https://docs.snipcart.com/configuration/custom-fields might be a better way. If not, you should be able to change the description by using `$('button').data('item-description', newDescription)`.

Comment: So, use this custom attributes.